# what type use for bitset type in C language

Tags: c, bitset

I have to define a bitset type to build bit arrays.
Between those arrays bit operations like and/or/xor could
be performed (to compare them, for example) and are
the predominant operations.
What type should I use as bitset type?

I think the type should be the widest NOT SIMULATED type
a compiler can handle.
I.e. if a compiler simulate a 64 bit type (if the machine
or the OS does not support it, for example) masking compound
operations between a simple and, a 32 bit type should be
used instead.
How to determine it?

And more questions:

new c99 header  defines some types (exact width
integer types), for which:

"These are of the form intN_t and uintN_t. Both types must be represented by exactly N bits with no padding bits. intN_t must be encoded as a two's complement signed integer and uintN_t as an unsigned integer. These types are optional unless the implementation supports types with widths of 8, 16, 32 or 64, then it shall typedef them to the corresponding types with corresponding N. Any other N is optional."

so I think think that implementations that checking for a 64 bit type
is a first step, right?

My project uses SDL library, that #defines a macro:

```
#ifdef SDL_HAS_64BIT_TYPE
typedef int64_t     Sint64;
#ifndef SYMBIAN32_GCCE
typedef uint64_t    Uint64;
#endif
#else
/* This is really just a hack to prevent the compiler from complaining */
typedef struct {
    Uint32 hi;
    Uint32 lo;
} Uint64, Sint64;
#endif
```

So perhaps I could make my definition of bitset type
depending of that macro (it is not optimal, however,
since I would like to write code sdl indipendent).

Tell me your opinions about.

Comment: the users of this data type aren't going to want it to vary size from platform to platform surely?

Comment: @David: Normally you make an array of the type for large bitsets, and then it doesn't matter what the size of the underlying type is, since it's hidden in the implementation. It's just the total number of bits in the array which you hold constant.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to determine the maximum size non-emulated integer type, and most people don't bother to try.  You can take either of two approaches, both of which work.

1. Decide that you will go with 32-bit integers because they are available everywhere.
2. Decide that you will have a configuration macro (not necessarily the one from SDL) which controls whether you use a 32-bit or 64-bit (or 16-bit, or 128-bit) data type.  You specify the 'right' value when you configure your build.

If you want to detect emulated vs native, you would probably run some timing tests on a test program with various sizes of multiplication.

Comment: We will also have to define what is native. Current x86 hardware can run two 32-bit ops in parallel in a single clock cycle. Does that make 64-bit ops "native" or are they still emulated? :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: presumably, you are talking about IA-32 chips, rather than either IA-64 or AMD x86/64 chips?  I think that on a 64-bit machine, both 32-bit and 64-bit multiplies would take about the same time, whereas on a 32-bit machine the 32-bit multiply would be (a lot) quicker than the 64-bit multiply; however, I've not demonstrated that.  I'm used to systems where a human specifies the sizes - so option 2 above.  Option 1 is going to give reasonable performance on many systems, even if not fully optimal.

Comment: I'm talking about the and/or/xor that the @dr wants to perform. Multiplications would be different.

Comment: @Bo Persson: True - once you've found the size of the 'native word' by seeing which multiply works fastest, you are going to do XOR etc in units of that word size.  And it is possibly agonizing over that which is not worth agonizing over - the 'assume 32-bit' heuristic is quite likely quite effective.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional Unix practice, for signal and fd sets, is to use `unsigned long` (actually historically it may even have been `long`, but using signed types for bitsets is a very very bad idea and almost surely leads to undefined behavior). While some ancient 16-bit machines may have had `long` larger than the system word size, I think you'll have a very hard time finding any modern machine with that problem. On the other hand, 64-bit Windows has 32-bit `long`, so you wouldn't get the optimal type, but you might as well just live with it for simplicity,

Another approach, if you have C99 `stdint.h` at your disposal, is to use `uintptr_t`. That's almost surely the machine word size.

Yet another approach, which definitely wins on simplicity, is just to always use bytes.

Finally, note that on little endian systems, the representation in memory will be identical regardless of what type size you use.